# What if "T" not defined in code?

Tags: java, generics

this is the code I have so far. Which converts map to object and runs as expected with no error.

But I have a question about how to generic works. Any replay will be appreciated.

**1. Why no error occurs although no generic 'T' is defined in the method or in the middle of the code?**

**2.  `<T>` in the method is like the indicator which informs the compile that this method uses character T as generic? My understanding is right?**

```
public static <T> T convertMapToObject(Map<String, Object> map, Object obj){

              try {
                Iterator<String> keyIter = map.keySet().iterator();

                Method[] methods = obj.getClass().getMethods();
                while(keyIter.hasNext()){
                    String key = keyIter.next(); 
                    String methodName = "set" + StringUtils.capitalize(key);
                    for(int i=0; i<methods.length; i++){
                        if(methodName.equals(methods[i].getName())){


                            Class<?> clazz = methods[i].getParameterTypes()[0]; //메서드 인수 타입
                            if (String.class == clazz){
                                methods[i].invoke(obj, String.valueOf(map.get(key)));
                            }
                            else {
                                methods[i].invoke(obj, map.get(key));
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                 return (T)obj;
              } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace(); 
                log.error(e);
            } 
          return null;
    }
---------------------------
        FileEx f= convertMapToObject(map, fileEx);
```

Comment: it's more convention than anything else

T is meant to be a Type
like E is meant to be an Element (List<E>: a list of Elements)
K is Key and V is Value (in a Map<K,V>)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Why no error occurs although no generic 'T' is defined in the method or in the middle of the code?

It >>is<< defined, in your example.

```
     public static <T> T convertMapToObject
                   ^^^ the generic type T is defined here!
```

It is not necessarily used in the method body, but that's OK.  Java doesn't insist that you use things that you define.  (Redundant variables, parameters, fields, methods, classes and so on call all legal Java.  Pointless ... but legal.)

> 2. `<T>` in the method is like the indicator which informs the compiler that this method uses character `T` as generic?

Yes ... sort of.  `T` is an identifier (not a character).  But yes, it does represent a generic type parameter, and `<T>` is saying that (i.e. it is declaring the type parameter).

---

In your example, `T` >>is<< used in the body; here:

```
     return (T) obj;
```

However, that usage will be flagged by the compiler as an "unchecked type cast" warning / error.  What it says is that the compiler won't be able to emit code that actually checks the type of the result at runtime.  That can lead to unexpected typecast exceptions *somewhere else in the code*; e.g. when the result of a `convertMapToObject` call is assigned to a variable with a concrete type.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Understood  loud and clear.